# Angular 2 template intellisense in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: angular, visual-studio-2015

Is there any way to get  intellisense in Visual Studio 2015 editor for Angular 2 template,

[image]

Comment: I've also been looking for something similar in the full Visual Studio 2017, but as far as I can tell there isn't anything, which is a bit disappointing. Even the standard templates that come with Visual Studio 2017 the Angular projects are for AngularJS. There are of course the new Angular 2 templates that you can install via command line, but these are just templates - no intellisense. There seem to be lots of intellisense extensions for Visual Studio code though and tbh I've started using this for my Angular 2 development and the template intellisense works brilliantly...